# Reduce white space between lines of text

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage (first time) and i'm following as much of the CSS rules and tags as I can.  However, I ran into a problem with white space.  I've underlined the first line of text but now the second line seems to have drifted below.  Is there a way to make it a bit more snug, i'd like the second line of text to be just below the above line.

```
body,td,th {
    color: #000000;
}

body { 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 padding-top: 6px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
} 
#centered
{ 
 width: 800px; /* set to desired width in px or percent */
 text-align: left; /* optionally you could use "justified" */
 border: 0px; /* Changing this value will add lines around the centered area */
 padding: 0;  
 margin: 0 auto; 
} 
.style3 {
    font-size: 32pt;
    color: #666666;
    margin-left: 0px;   
    border-bottom: 3px double;
}
.style5 {
    margin-left: 390px;
    font-size: 32pt;
    color: #CCCCCC;

}
-->

</style></head>

<div id="centered">


<body>
<p class="style3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FIRST LINE OF TEXT</p>
<p class="style5">INDENTED SECOND LINE</p>
</body>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @jnpcl, close, but I think it will more likely be margin when talking about P tags.

Comment: @Stargazer712: Whoops. `margin` it is. :)

Comment: You have two `body`-closing elements. O.o

Answer (score 6):

You need to adjust the [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#line-height). More specifically, add the following declaration:

```
.style5 {
    line-height: 0.72em;
}
```

If you only want the first line of `.style5` to be snug, you need to adjust the top margin. Use this declaration instead:

```
.style5 {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBbch/1/).

**Note:** You should always validate your markup using the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org) and your css using the [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). It will help you a lot when you're starting out.

Answer (score 5):

```
p.style3, p.style5 {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Play with those two values until you are happy with the result :)

Comment: Stargazer712, thanks...excellent results !  the margin tags worked great.

Comment: @melhosseiny, right you are. Should have read all of the markup :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the CSS line-height rule?
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 1):

hmm. your code little buggy. first i see that you have div **OUTSIDE** of body tag.

try to validate your code.

anyway you can change the space weebven lines in the same paragraph with : `p {line-height:0.7em}` this creates a 7/10 line height of the font size.

if you want to decrease space between paragrapsh you shold change the margin|padding of the paragraphs. `p{margin:0 91px 0 37px;padding:0 43px 0 19px}`